# Overview of ARM-MCUs

Tags: arm

Is there a place to compare ARM-MCUs of different manufacturers?

something like this but way bigger:

http://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/ARM_Selektor

Answer (score 3):

Good overviews can be found at the Wikipedia lists for [ARM processor cores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_microprocessor_cores) and [Applications of ARM cores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_applications_of_ARM_cores).  You'll probably want to filter your search significantly - Trying to find a basic 32-bit controller in the ARM7TDMI or Cortex-M3 series is a very different task than trying to find a multicore applications processor for your consumer product.

Of course, if you're looking for certain specifications, distributor parametric searches can be helpful.  For example, both Digikey and Mouser have Microcontroller ([1](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Cat=2556109), [2](http://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Integrated-Circuits-ICs/Embedded-Processors-MCU-MPU-DSP-DSC-SoC/Microcontrollers-MCU/_/N-8ob9a?P=1yzug2lZ1yzud1pZ1yzud8sZ1yztkjiZ1yzud1cZ1yzsvcrZ1yzudvyZ1yzuqcvZ1yzujc6Z1yzu3p9Z1yzud2pZ1yzsp20Z1yzuqfbZ1yzud7lZ1yzudi9Z1yzudc0Z1yzuqehZ1yzuda4Z1yzuqduZ1yzud9hZ1yzud54Z1yzud55)) and Microprocessor ([1](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Cat=2556260), [2](http://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Integrated-Circuits-ICs/Embedded-Processors-MCU-MPU-DSP-DSC-SoC/Microprocessors-MPU/_/N-8ob91?P=1yzud1yZ1yzuc4gZ1yzuda4Z1yzuqdu)) pages with good selection tools.

Finally, some compiler/IDE/software providers maintain lists of the processors they support.  For instance, Keil's [device database](http://www.keil.com/dd/parms/arm.htm) has information about [these ARM based chips](http://www.keil.com/dd/chips/all/arm.htm).

Those links notwithstanding, if you want to exhaustively compare manufacturers, you will have to make some phone calls.

Comment: I've made this answer community wiki, please update if the links change or new tables become available.  Also note that this answer's prose style works well for the limited number of links currently given, bulleted lists may be required as the answer grows.